# About amazon url , what means "i:aps","p_72","p_78","ssx:relevance"

Tags: php, html, url, amazon-product-api

I want to know Amazon URL detail

for example,

```
https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/?keywords=iPhone+SE+%E3%82%AC%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A0&ie=UTF8&field-
```

asin=XXXXXXXX&rh=i:aps,ssx:relevance

this URL includes `i:aps","ssx:relevance`

i want to know this paramater,

And below URL

```
https://www.amazon.co.jp/s?k=メンズ 洗顔&rh=p_78:XXXXXXXX,ssx:relevance&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=IGShopping
```

this URL includes "p_78"

I want to know this parameter.

I also saw "p_72" , pls let me know.

If there is another URL starting with P, please tell me

XXXXXXX is amazon ASIN

Comment: What do you mean by know this parameter? You want to retrieve this value from URL string or you want to know what is this parameter stands for?

Comment: What makes you think that we know all the ins and outs of Amazons naming convention of URL parameters?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What makes you think none of us DO know?

Comment: Do consider this https://kindlepreneur.com/amazon-super-url/